# Query not returning any results

Tags: php, mysql

I know that $wins should be 3. Because I have 3 rows with the integer "1" in the "win" column on table "rated_teams" But for some reason this code will not work. Can you find the problem please? ALSO, I'm aware that some of this is depracted. I'll update the whole page, once I get it at least in working condition.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT SUM(win) FROM rated_teams WHERE server='$server' AND name='$myteam'";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $con) 
or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());    
while ((mysql_fetch_array($query)))     {                           
$wins = $row['SUM(win)'];                    
}
?>
<h3>Total Wins: <?php echo $wins?> </h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(win) as sum FROM rated_teams WHERE server='$server' AND name='$myteam'";
```

and while you are getting give like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {                           
    $wins = $row['sum'];                    
}
```

And my advice is try to avoid `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO statements`.

Comment: that you that got it!

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the $row variable. Edit your while to this.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your calculated column an alias. Try this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT SUM(win) as sumwin FROM rated_teams WHERE server='$server' AND name='$myteam'";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))     {                           
$wins = $row['sumwin'];                    
}  
?>
<h3>Total Wins: <?php echo $wins?> </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write sql query right manner.Write like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(win) as sumwin FROM rated_teams WHERE server='".$server."' AND name='".$myteam."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((mysql_fetch_array($query)))   {
```

should be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )  {
```